# Center Responsive items with CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I am learning CSSGrid and I require that in a responsive view the widgets are aligned to the center but I can not do it.

This is my code:

```
grid-template-areas: "header   header  header"
                     "contenido contenido sidebar"
                     "widget-1 widget-2 sidebar"
                     "footer footer footer";

.contenedor .sidebar {
    /* grid-column: 3/4; */
    background: #faa43d;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    /* grid-row: span 2; */

    min-height: 100px;
    grid-area: sidebar;

}

.contenedor .widget-1,
.contenedor .widget-2 {
    background: #55a8fd;
    color: white;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.contenedor .widget-1 {
    grid-area: widget-1;
}

.contenedor .widget-2 {
    grid-area: widget-2;
}
```

I use media query for the responsive view where I indicate the "contenido" class occupies 3 columns and the sidebar also but the problem is that the widget uses 2 columns so it does not occupy the 3 columns of my Grid. I can solve it by using a point in the media query in the area of ​​the widget.

But I do not know how to center them since the point occupies a space that would be the 3rd so it does not allow me to center them

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .contenedor {
        grid-template-areas: 
        "header   header  header"
        "contenido contenido contenido"
        "sidebar sidebar sidebar"
        "widget-1  widget-2 ."
        "footer footer footer";
    }
}
```

Attached image of how it looks when the media query comes in. Thanks.

[image]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Layout CSS-GRID</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <header class="header">
            <h2>HEADER</h2>
        </header>
        <main class="contenido">
            <h1>Contenido</h1>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur
                adipisicing elit. 
                Dolores, ullam. 
                Repellat eaque unde quam aliquid porro,
                consequatur non dolorum corporis nulla,
                consequuntur accusantium, 
                blanditiis accusamus aut exercitationem 
                placeat eligendi quis!
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur
                adipisicing elit. 
                Dolores, ullam. 
                Repellat eaque unde quam aliquid porro,
                consequatur non dolorum corporis nulla,
                consequuntur accusantium, 
                blanditiis accusamus aut exercitationem 
                placeat eligendi quis!
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur
                adipisicing elit. 
                Dolores, ullam. 
                Repellat eaque unde quam aliquid porro,
                consequatur non dolorum corporis nulla,
                consequuntur accusantium, 
                blanditiis accusamus aut exercitationem 
                placeat eligendi quis!
                <br><br>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur
                adipisicing elit. 
                Dolores, ullam. 
                Repellat eaque unde quam aliquid porro,
                consequatur non dolorum corporis nulla,
                consequuntur accusantium, 
                blanditiis accusamus aut exercitationem 
                placeat eligendi quis!
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur
                adipisicing elit. 
                Dolores, ullam. 
                Repellat eaque unde quam aliquid porro,
                consequatur non dolorum corporis nulla,
                consequuntur accusantium, 
                blanditiis accusamus aut exercitationem 
                placeat eligendi quis!
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur
                adipisicing elit. 
                Dolores, ullam. 
                Repellat eaque unde quam aliquid porro,
                consequatur non dolorum corporis nulla,
                consequuntur accusantium, 
                blanditiis accusamus aut exercitationem 
                placeat eligendi quis!
                <br><br>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur
                adipisicing elit. 
                Dolores, ullam. 
                Repellat eaque unde quam aliquid porro,
                consequatur non dolorum corporis nulla,
                consequuntur accusantium, 
                blanditiis accusamus aut exercitationem 
                placeat eligendi quis!
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur
                adipisicing elit. 
                Dolores, ullam. 
                Repellat eaque unde quam aliquid porro,
                consequatur non dolorum corporis nulla,
                consequuntur accusantium, 
                blanditiis accusamus aut exercitationem 
                placeat eligendi quis!
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur
                adipisicing elit. 
                Dolores, ullam. 
                Repellat eaque unde quam aliquid porro,
                consequatur non dolorum corporis nulla,
                consequuntur accusantium, 
                blanditiis accusamus aut exercitationem 
                placeat eligendi quis!
            </p>
        </main>
        <aside class="sidebar">
            <h3>Sidebar</h3>
        </aside>
        <div class="widget-1">
            <h3>Widget 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-2">
                <h3>Widget 2</h3>
        </div>
        <footer class="footer">
            <h3>FOOTER</h3>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: Just based on this, you could always add more grid columns, and center them that way. You would have to re-position all the items in your grid template-areas accordingly, but thankfully since it's a grid, you'd only have to do it once.

Comment: Ok but I do not know how to do it, so I published my friend

Comment: I think I understood you instead of doing 3 columns I did 4 and now I put something like:. widget-1 widget-2.

Comment: Yes. I was thinking something like - `grid-template-areas: 
        "header   header  header  header   header  header"
        "contenido contenido contenido contenido contenido contenido"
        "sidebar sidebar sidebar sidebar sidebar sidebar"
        ". widget-1 widget-1  widget-2 widget 2 ."
        "footer footer footer footer footer footer";`

Comment: You might have to copy and paste that to see the alignment better. Although i'm not sure if this will preserve the gap between the widgets. But I think you have the idea. Play around with it - I always find it helps to draw grids out on a piece of paper and plan my rows and columns that way.

Comment: what you showed in the image, it's not possible to align those two elements, they are in a `grid`. I mean, that's why it's called grid, right ?